# onMouseOver requires click before becoming active

Tags: javascript, onmouseover

I have a problem with onMouseOver event on a div. I have searched the forums and tried to apply some of the solutions proposed here for similar events, but have not found it working yet. It is probably simple, but cannot figure it out myself; I am probably searching in the wrong direction. Does anybody has any tips?

```
function toggleHeight (e, maxHeight) {
    e = document.getElementById("small");

    if(e.style.height != '1.2em') {
        e.style.height = '1.2em';

    }   else {
        e.style.height = maxHeight + 'px';
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#!" onMouseOver="toggleHeight(this,180); return false" style="display:block;">Menu</a>
```

Comment: Thats not jquery at all

Comment: Also why are you passing `this` to toggleHeight and then immediately overwriting it?

Comment: Whate are you trying to achieve my friend? Please provide us details please create a example on jsfiddle.net. its totally free

Comment: HTML attribute names are case insensitive. Their property name equivalents are always lower case so for consistency it's usual to write them in lower case in the HTML also so that the `onmouseover` attribute correlates to the `onmouseover` property.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know about your method and you have done many mistake but here is the code of what you want i mean you want to change the height of div and why you have written `a` tag when you have mentioned `div` tag before... however here is the code. go ahead and copy this code and then paste in your code editor... and this is perfectly working, i tested this...

```
    <html>
    <style type="text/css">
    #link{
        background-color: lime;
        width:200px;
    }   
        </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var toogleH = function(h){
            //alert("sanmevg");
            var x = document.getElementById("link");
            x.style.height = h;
        };

        var toogleA = function(a){
            var v = document.getElementById("link");
            v.style.height = a;
            };

    </script>
    <body>
      <div id="link" onmouseover ="toogleH('100');" onmouseout="toogleA('20');">sanmveg</div>
    </body>

</html>
```

---

### suggestions:

1) in your tag when you write `toogleHeight` you must quote the height in single quote.
always remember it is always `e.style.height = '180'` not `e.style.height = 180` that means you must always write a string. if you want any css change such as `e.style.backgroundColor= "lime"`. so when you pass the parameters that is when you type attribute to any tag such as to change its css then you must type `onmouseover=" toogleHeight('180');"` not `onmouseover=" toogleHeight(180);`, watch the quote around 180 because as i told you earlier you must give a sting to javascript containing a number or words to change any tag's css.

2) Use `px` insted of `em` because of some reasons.. Now in your code you have written `e.style.height = maxHeight + 'px';` dont write px because in CSS `width:200px;` is same as `width:200;`. this means that you should write simply `e.style.height = maxHeight;`